# How to copy table from one Data Base to another?

Tags: sql, copy, ssms

I want to copy some tables from my DB1 to my DB2. Tables in DB1 are same as tables on DB2 but data in the tables are different. I want to copy tables from DB1 to DB2 but to keep old tables and data on DB2. How I can do this with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio? I tried to right click and do the export but before I have to click on Finish button looks like that will just copt all data from DB1 to DB2 and I do not want that. If anyone can help with this please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: are both your tables on the same server? Also are you using MySQL or tSQL

Comment: they are on different servers and I just want to make copt of table from DB1 to DB2 and keep same name. I use mySQL.

Comment: have you tried using the import export wizard as suggested by Thomas in his answer

Comment: I was doing that but on the final step it looks that my data will be replaced from on table to another and I do not want that I just want to make a copy of the existing table in DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the tables from DB1 with another name to DB2 if you don't want to modify them. In the export wizard just change the name of the destination table.

Comment: Should I just put word copy on the end of the table that I will export that way I can see what is the old and what is existing table?

Comment: yes just add a suffix in the destination name and you will easily identify the copied table.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to merge the schema AND data from DB1 into DB2?

You should list out the exact requirements, the question is still vague even with that info.
What data do you want to keep, what is ok to blow out?
What schema do you want to keep, are you archiving the old tables? Changing table names?

If you are literally trying to merge db1 into db2 your issue is going to be in managing the relationship ids which will be getting reassigned since DB2 could already be using IDs that are present in DB1.

Comment: I have two servers, on both servers I have same tables but different data in the tables. I want to keep same table names and just make an extra copy on DB2  from DB1.

Comment: Well you are going to need to put something on the name at the destination to differentiate between them. I'm not 100% but I don't think using the export wizard is going to maintain relationships on the 'new' tables either if you care about that.

thomas tuyaerts  has the simplest way.

Comment: How I can just make copy from one table to another if they are in different DB. In my case from DB1 to DB2? I tried and I got an error: Validating (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "SectionId".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep old data in the destination table (or juste update it), so you might use a [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb510625%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
MERGE INTO db2.dbo.table1 B
USING (
  SELECT *
  FROM db1.dbo.table1) A
ON (A.Column1 = B.Column1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  -- update
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  -- insert new rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE db2;

CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE db1.table1;

INSERT INTO table2  
    SELECT * FROM db1.table1;
```

This is also a way to copy a table with its records to another database.